# PHP mail command won't work if "http://" is in the body

Tags: php, email

Strangest thing I've ever seen.  If the string "http://" is used in the mail body, the mail command does not work.  If any other combo of these characters is used, it DOES send.  For example I can type "ttp://"  or "http:/"  and that will send fine.  As soon as I have the exact string "http://" anywhere in the body, the mail does not send.

Doesn't work:

```
$mail_body = 'http://';
$subject = "Test subject"; 
$recipient =  "myemail@myemail.com";

$header = "MIME-Version: 1.0\n" ;
$header .= "Content-type: text/html; charset: utf8\r\n";
$header = $header . 'From: test@test.com';

mail($recipient, $subject, $mail_body, $header) or die('mail could not be sent');
```

The above DOES work if you change $mail_body, for example:

$mail_body = 'ttp://';

or

$mail_body = 'http:/';

or

any other combination of any other characters imaginable, just not when it says http://

Comment: Please post the code you're using to send the email.

Comment: Not enough info :(
1. Do you use shared hosting? 1.1. Ask hosting provider if they block email with links
2. Are you sure that emails are sent successfully? 2.1. What does mail() function returns?

Comment: I added some more info.  this is a VPS

Comment: 1st thing, don't influence on sending, but, right encoding is utf-8, not utf8. 
Did you try to remove headers at all? I mean MIME-TYPE and CONTENT-TYPE/ENCODING.

Answer (score 0):

If you are adding "http" in your body, try to send email using "html" format. It will work, since we have send may emails contains link "http"

```
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";
```

Use the above character set and your code will work

Answer (score 0):

Replace `http://` with `http%3A//`